# ivy report for entire repo?

Tags: build, build-process, ivy

I'm working on an internal ivy repository with a decent number of projects under it, each with many revisions.  I would like to make a dependency report for the entire repository showing which versions of which artifacts depend on which revisions of other artifacts.  Obviously it isn't too difficult to make a script to parse the published ivy xml files, but if this functionality exists already I'll use that.  Something like the repreport task would be nice, but for a whole repo.

My main goal here is to get a report of artifacts that are not referenced by any other artifacts so as to make a list of candidates for removal from the repo.

So, does ivy have any way to build a dependency report against and entire repository?

Edit: Working through this, it looks like ivy:repreport is the way to go.

Here is my build.xml file:

```
<project name="Report Build" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" basedir=".">
    <property name="ivy.version" value="2.2.0"/>
    <property name="ivy.home" value="${user.home}/.ivy2"/>

    <target name="fetch-ivy" unless="offline" description="Install Ivy if it doesn't already exist">
        <mkdir dir="${ivy.home}"/>
        <get
                src="http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/${ivy.version}/ivy-${ivy.version}.jar"
                dest="${ivy.home}" usetimestamp="true"/>
    </target>

    <target name="init-ivy" depends="fetch-ivy" unless="ivy-initialized">
        <path id="ivy.lib.path">
            <fileset dir="${ivy.home}" includes="*.jar"/>
        </path>
        <taskdef resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" classpathref="ivy.lib.path"/>
        <property name="ivy-initialized" value="yes"/>
    </target>

    <target name="report" depends="init-ivy">
        <ivy:settings file="ivy-settings-report.xml" id="report.ivy.settings"/>
        <ivy:repreport settingsref="report.ivy.settings"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

And here is my ivy settings file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-settings>
    <settings defaultResolver="main"/>
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="main">
            <url name="internalartifacts" m2compatible="false">
                <artifact
                        pattern="http://internalartifacts.local/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>
                <ivy pattern="http://internalartifacts.local/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/ivy-[revision].xml"/>
            </url>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivy-settings>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [repreport](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/use/repreport.html) says:

> To generate a xml report for all the latest versions of all the
>   modules in your repository:
>
> ```
> <ivy:repreport />
> ```
>
> **Limitation**: this task requires to be able to browse the repository,
>   and is thus limited to resolvers supporting repository listing. In
>   particular, it means it doesn't work to report all organizations in a
>   repository using m2compatible mode. Moreover, to be able to list
>   organizations, this task requires an [organisation] token in the
>   resolver(s) used.

So this should totally work.

As mentioned in the comment:
It is important that your repository has `ivy.xml` files for the artifacts in it. Otherwise ivy cannot recognize the dependencies between the artifacts and your report will be empty.

Comment: I'd tried running that, but it comes back with no results and generated an empty xml file.  I'm looking it now and I'm not sure how it works.  If I just run ivy:repreport, how does it know which repo to use?  I have several in my ivy-settings.  I noticed a option for the task that can take a separate settings file... is that so I can specify a single repo?

Comment: I would create a special ivysettings.xml that is just used for that report (only has one resolver/repo).

Comment: I've created a small build.xml file and a special ivy settings file for the purpose of this.  Running it still produces an empty report though.  I've edited the original post with full listings of the relevant files.

Comment: Running ant with -v I was able to see the errors coming from the process.  It seems that ivy is looking for an xml file in the root of each project directory in the repo.  The publish process we're using doesn't generate any such file.  We're only making versioned directories, which contain the artifacts and related metadata.  The answer provided by @ooers is likely correct for others, but it seems that it won't work for my case.  I hope this thread can at least be useful for other people though.

Comment: do you have directory listing enabled in your webserver? can you browse to http://internalartifacts.local/ and see all organizations?

Comment: Yeah, it is browseable.  It's just a simple apache instance with full directory listings enabled.